# How to check user already purchased or not using In-App Purchase in iOS based on apple ID

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I want to know how to check if already purchased or not based on apple id as I don’t have login in my app.

Below is my code:

```
(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
}
```

Any help how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app starts the process by calling the

> restoreCompletedTransactions method of SKPaymentQueue class

This sends a request to the App Store to restore all of your app’s completed transactions. If your app sets a value for the applicationUsername property of its payment requests, as described in Detecting Irregular Activity, use the

> restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:

method to provide the same information when restoring transactions.

Your transaction queue observer is called with a status of SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored for each restored transaction, as described in Waiting for the App Store to Process Transactions. The action you take at this point depends on the design of your app.

```
NSMutableArray *productIDsToRestore = <# From the user #>;
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = <# Current transaction #>;

if ([productIDsToRestore containsObject:transaction.transactionIdentifier]) {
    // Re-download the Apple-hosted content, then finish the transaction
    // and remove the product identifier from the array of product IDs.
} else {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

Read the Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9).

Comment: @ Amit Are we going to get transactions based on Apple Id?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of previous transactions from the store with -`[SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions]`. The restored transactions can be verified just like normal transactions.